# Can't fetch with Mongoose but working with Mongo shell

Tags: find, mongoose, fetch

I am playing around with Mongoose and Node.

A want to be able to save a Backbone model, and fetch the saved models from Mongo via Mongoose.

I am able to save models but I can't fetch them via Mongoose. I can access them via the Mongo shell with no problems using:

```
db.users.find()
```

My code is:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
userschema = mongoose.Schema({name: 'string', email: 'string'}),
db = mongoose.createConnection('localhost', 'test'),
User = db.model('User', userschema);

exports.save = function(req, res){
var userobj = req.body,
    newuser = new User(userobj);

newuser.save(function(err){
    if(err){
        res.send(err);
    }
    else{
        res.send(newuser);
    }
});
};

exports.fetch = function(req, res){
var users = User.find();
res.send(users);
}
```

When I send a request and executes my fetch function the server responds with

```
{
  "options": {
    "populate": {}
  },
  "_conditions": {},
  "_updateArg": {},
  "op": "find"
}
```

It is like I am not on the right Collection or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`User.find()` doesn't return the results of the query; those are passed to the callback that you provide as a parameter to `find`.

```js
exports.fetch = function(req, res) {
    User.find(function(err, users) {
        res.send(users);
    });
};
```

If you don't provide a callback, then a [`Query`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query-js) object is returned (which is what you're seeing in the response).